# call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::pos()

Tags: php, lumen

> call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::pos().

Iam getting this error when am trying to access some routes in my project.

Comment: Doe to lack of information, I can only guess what do you want. What are you trying to do? Create post route?

Comment: Looks like a typo. Did you mean to call: `Router::post()`? Please include your code that triggers this error.

Comment: Since we haven't gotten any clarification, I'm voting to close this as a typo

Answer (score 0):

don't write this
       call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::pos()
write as this one
       call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::post()